# How to extract text from between the <br> tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, line-breaks

What i am trying to do is to scrape only the companies names from the `<td>` element, which has multiple `<br>` tags. FYI, some `<td>` have one company name while others have two. See `<td>` element below:

```
<td id="MainContent_DisassociatedRegistrationsCell" colspan="2">
<p style="background-color:#CCCCCC;width:100%;text-align:center">
<strong>License #: 
<a href="LicenseDetail.aspx?LicNum=332673">332673</a>
</strong>
</p>
BAY AREA REMODELING CO
<br>
5230 EAST 12TH
<br>
OAKLAND, CA 94601
<br>
<strong>Effective Dates:</strong>
09/16/1982 - 06/30/1984
<p style="background-color:#CCCCCC;width:100%;text-align:center">
<strong>License #: 
<a href="LicenseDetail.aspx?LicNum=377133">377133</a>
</strong>
</p>
SAVAGE ROOFING COMPANY
<br>
3055 ALVARADO STREET
<br>
SAN LEANDRO, CA 94577
<br>
<strong>Effective Dates:</strong>
 07/01/1982 - 03/31/1985
</td>
```

So from the above `<td>` element, i want the output:

```
BAY AREA REMODELING CO
SAVAGE ROOFING COMPANY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `next_sibling` after finding the required `p` tag

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<td id="MainContent_DisassociatedRegistrationsCell" colspan="2">
<p style="background-color:#CCCCCC;width:100%;text-align:center">
<strong>License #: 
<a href="LicenseDetail.aspx?LicNum=332673">332673</a>
</strong>
</p>
BAY AREA REMODELING CO
<br>
5230 EAST 12TH
<br>
OAKLAND, CA 94601
<br>
<strong>Effective Dates:</strong>
09/16/1982 - 06/30/1984
<p style="background-color:#CCCCCC;width:100%;text-align:center">
<strong>License #: 
<a href="LicenseDetail.aspx?LicNum=377133">377133</a>
</strong>
</p>
SAVAGE ROOFING COMPANY
<br>
3055 ALVARADO STREET
<br>
SAN LEANDRO, CA 94577
<br>
<strong>Effective Dates:</strong>
 07/01/1982 - 03/31/1985
</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(p.next_sibling.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
BAY AREA REMODELING CO
SAVAGE ROOFING COMPANY
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> [p.next_sibling.strip() for p in soup.findAll("p")]
['BAY AREA REMODELING CO', 'SAVAGE ROOFING COMPANY']
```

Comment: thanks man.. it worked very well. comprehensions are really useful.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember upvotes are also here to thank contributions ;)

Comment: Surely i know sir,and i have done that but upvotes of those whose reputation is < 15 are not shown publicly. @Arnaud